# Where is the text for the symbol stored in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, symbol

The following is an image of the symbol `opamp.asy`.
[image: LTspice symbol with text]

I opened the same file using `Notepad++` and have pasted the contents below:

```
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal -32 32 32 64
LINE Normal -32 96 32 64
LINE Normal -32 32 -32 96
LINE Normal -28 48 -20 48
LINE Normal -28 80 -20 80
LINE Normal -24 84 -24 76
WINDOW 0 0 32 Left 0
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR Description Ideal single-pole operational amplifier. You must .lib opamp.sub
SYMATTR Value opamp
SYMATTR SpiceLine Aol=100K
SYMATTR SpiceLine2 GBW=10Meg
PIN -32 48 NONE 0
PINATTR PinName invin
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN -32 80 NONE 0
PINATTR PinName noninvin
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
PIN 32 64 NONE 0
PINATTR PinName out
PINATTR SpiceOrder 3
```

I am surprised to find that the text `Unnn` is missing in the file. Where is this text stored? For example, if I make a symbol `my_symbol.asy`, and using the GUI I add some text to it reading `this_is_my_symbol`, then the file `my_symbol.asy` does contain the aforementioned string when opened in a text-editor.

Is this different for the symbols and the subcircuits shipped with LTspice? In that case where are such strings stored?

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in the .asc file that contains your circuit. This makes sense because you don't want to store the name for a specific part in the part file, rather anything you rename a part(C1, C2, C3, Etc) gets stored in the .asc file which contains the components and wiring of your circuit.

Edit: I understand now what you were asking. The line SYMATTR Prefix X is the line that the U is stored under. I don't know why the character X shows up as a U for the opamp but if you change that character to an A and open the model you'll see Annn instead. Every other character, including multiple characters, I changed the value to was mirrored in ltspice when i opend the .asy file.

Comment: I opened the `.asy` file without having added it to any `.asc` file. So it seems unlikely that the string `Unnn` is stored in my `.asc` file (that's because I haven't created any `.asc` file in the first place). Hence the question.